# Read Files across File Systems (PyCharm Windows/WSL)

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using [PyCharm with a WSL interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) because I need to use a library that doesn't work well with Windows ([gtsam](https://gtsam.org/tutorials/intro.html), if you're wondering).

I have a pandas Dataframe stored as a pickle file on my "regular" workspace, e.g. "C:\some\windows\path\to\file.pkl", and I want to read it in my WSL-PyCharm environment.

Obviously I can copy the file to my WSL machine and read it from its new path.
However I'm hoping for a "cleaner" solution that doesn't involve making multiple copies of huge pkl files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, WSL should mount your `C:` drive at `/mnt/c`, so you should be able to access your file as `/mnt/c/some/windows/path/to/file.pkl`.

Comment: But how to open WSL-only locations, like `~`?

Comment: Actually I found it - in Pycharm go to menu `File / Open...`, `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` location will be available (assuming `Ubuntu` is used)

Answer (score 0):

For folks searching for a way to open **WSL-only locations**, like `~`, in **Pycharm**:

1. In Pycharm go to menu `File / Open...`
2. `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` location should be available in the locations list (assuming `Ubuntu` is used). Just select `/home/<your_username>`